# Unable to install Latest Xamarin Android Nuget Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

I facing a problems when I want to update the Latest Xamarin Android Nuget Visual Studio 2013.
As below is the Photo.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are running into a limitation with `Xamarin.Forms` and the `Xamarin.Android Support` NuGet packages. `Xamarin Forms` have a hard dependency on a specific version of the support packages and thus updating them will not work, you have to use the specific version that `Xamarin.Forms` expects:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/#Error_Unable_to_find_a_version_of_Xamarin.Forms_compatible_with...

**EX:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

**MonoAndroid 1.0**

- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)

Thus with the current stable (2.3.0.107), you must only use the 23.3.0 version of the support libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned Xamarin.Android but the error relates to Xamarin.Forms, if you are using Xamarin.Forms try uninstalling all Xamarin related packages, reinstall `Xamarin.Forms` first and then each page from this screenshot you need one by one. Give that a shot.